# What are GIS methods for temporal analysis for poor data?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-statistics, spatio-temporal-data

I'm interested to know what GIS methods or techniques there are for operationalising time-series data for spatial/temporal regression analysis where data have temporal data gaps.

For instance, if I am analysing survey data of a region, with survey data at 0, 5, 10 year snapshots, but want to employ some controls to assess temporal variations in data, what are some ways this can be done?

Comment: I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.